# selenium-wire does not open the target website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I don't know what to do. I'm trying to get access to the `https://visa.vfsglobal.com/rus/ru/hun/login` using **selenium-wire** but it does not work.

Why does a default **selenium** open the page and **selenium-wire** does not? How can I fix it?

Why I use selenium wire? Because I need to use proxies and default **selenium** doesn't support proxies like `<PROXY_PROTOCOL>://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY_IP_ADDRESS>:<PROXY_PORT>`.

When I found that it doesn't work for me, I tried to open webpage without proxy but with selenium-wire:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

def setConnectionOldWay(url: str):
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
    driver_vfs = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
    driver_vfs.get(url)
    time.sleep(10000)
```

But even so, I was getting an error: "Sorry, you have been blocked" by cloudfare.

I found [here](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire?tab=readme-ov-file#bot-detection) that it is possible to use `import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc` but again the same issue.

Note that when I use default `selenium` this website downloads without errors.